# How to proportionally fill a space around a fixed size div?

Tags: css, html, markup

Could someone please help me?

I have three divs.

```
enter code here
```

- The one in the middle should always be 1040px.
- The left and right one shall fill the whole left space.

How can I make them proportionally grow/shrink when I resize the window?

Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/christophz/pen/413d31df9d33e1205b73bed3ebee1f5d

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: your code isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS option using CSS display properties of `table` and `table-cell`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/a9J7D/

The markup is the same as you proposed.

The CSS is:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    min-width: 540px; /* you may want this... */
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px dashed blue;
    display: table;
}
.bar-light {
    width: auto;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
}
.bar-dark {
    width: 540px;
    height: 52px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Set `display: table` to `.container` and for the child elements, `display: table-cell`.

For `.bar-light`, set the width to auto and they will be computed to fill in the remainder of the page width (equally).

In my example, I set the center width to 540px to make it easier to see in the fiddle.

Finally, add a `min-width` to `.container`, without any content, the table cells will collapse to zero width as you shrink the window size.

**Note About Heights**

This layout will create three columns of equal height, the height will be computed to enclose the tallest of the three child elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is real quick so it might be slightly off but you should be able to get the idea

HTML

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

CSS

```
div { float: left;}
.b { width: 1040px;}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).onload(resize);
$(window).resize(resize);
function resize() {
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var width = (ww-1040)/2;
    $('.a').width(width);
    $('.b').width(width);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a table with 3 column. In the middle column add you div. specify the size you want for this for these column e.g. 10-80-10. or *-80-*.

Comment: A table? Really? Are u kidding me?